LaTeX command for sets of elements set using \mathtt?
I teach a course in automata and computability theory and often have to define alphabets (sets of symbols). Typically, using amsmath, I write things like this:
Let $\Sigma = \set{\mathtt{a}, \mathtt{b}, \mathtt{c}}$

While this works, I spend a lot of time typing out the repeated \mathtt commands. Is there a way to define a command (say, \alphabet) where I could write something like this?
Let $\Sigma = \alphabet{a, b, c}$

This command would be given to students in a LaTeX template. However, since I use MathJax for the course website, it would be great if whatever solution exists that also works in that context.

Welcome! To avoid your question getting closed as off-topic, can you remove the reference to MathJax? It doesn't use TeX at all so is outside the scope of this site. If you also want to use this in TeX or LaTeX (or ConTeXt etc.), that part would be on-topic, however. Can you provide a complete example or at least tell us which format you are using? (Formats include plain, LaTeX, ConTeXt etc.)

Well, you could do
\newcommand{\alphabet}[1]{\{\mathtt{#1}\}}

and, lo and behold, it also works in MathJax!

In a LaTeX document:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\alphabet}[1]{\{\mathtt{#1}\}}

\begin{document}

$\alphabet{a,b,c}$

$\alphabet{A,B,C}$

\end{document}


